# Uncaught ReferenceError: http_1 is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript

I understand there are a lot of this, seeing as it is a common problem that can vary by a lot.

I get the http_1 error yet I have defined it.

This is the line I get the error on

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: 
   string, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

 }
```

And I have imported HttpClient at the beginning

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

It used to work in other services, but suddenly it just stopped even though the code is quite literally the same.

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class MakeService
{
 CurrentId: number;
 CurrentName: string;
 CurrentAbrv: string;
 public makes: Makes[];


 constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: 
 string, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

 }

 GetId() {

this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
  const id = parseInt(paramMap.get('id'), 10) || -1;
  this.GetMakeObjectById(id);
});
 }

GetMakeObjectById(id) {
  this.http.get<Makes[]>(this.baseUrl + "api/SampleData/DetailsMake/" + 
 id).subscribe(result => {
  this.makes = result;

 }, error => console.error(error));
}
}


interface Makes {
Id: number;
 Name: string;
 Abrv: string;
}
```

Comment: I imported the service in the class I call it and put a `providers: [MakeService]`
Edit: Someone asked if I registered the service

Comment: your class isn't decorated as a `Component` or an `Injectible`, so it can't be part of a Module...meaning there's no DI here or Injector tree. Error is probably coming from the `@Inject` decorator, but none of the constructor parameters will be injected.

Comment: I see, I did not know it had to be defined as a component or injectible. Will there be a problem later on if I decorate it as a Component?

Comment: If you want Angular to inject any of these services or tokens into your class, it needs to be part of the Angular application. You can't add non-decorated classes to an `NgModule`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// You were missing @Injectable()

import { Component, Inject, OnInit , Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class MakeService{
 CurrentId: number;
 CurrentName: string;
 CurrentAbrv: string;
 public makes: Makes[];


 constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: 
 string, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

 }

 GetId() {

this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
  const id = parseInt(paramMap.get('id'), 10) || -1;
  this.GetMakeObjectById(id);
});
 }

GetMakeObjectById(id) {
  this.http.get<Makes[]>(this.baseUrl + "api/SampleData/DetailsMake/" + 
 id).subscribe(result => {
  this.makes = result;

 }, error => console.error(error));
}
}


interface Makes {
Id: number;
 Name: string;
 Abrv: string;
}
```